# SuiteScript deploying script Fail to evaluate script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am making a usereventcript that computes for the rate using subfields from the sales order item list. trying to save and deploy the script launches an error Fail to evaluate script: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":"missing } after property list (SS_SCRIPT_FOR_METADATA#32)","stack":[]}

[image]

```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.x
*@NScriptType UserEventScript
*/
define(
[
    'N/record'
],
function (record) {

    /**
    * @param {UserEventContext.beforeSubmit} context
    */
     function beforeSubmit(context) {
        //get taxcode
        var taxcode = context.newRecord.getValue({
            fieldId: 'taxcode'
          });
        if(taxcode !== 0 || taxcode !== 4){
            // Gets the Total Amount
            var amount = context.getValue.getValue({
              fieldId: "amount"
            });

        // Gets the quantity of an item selected
        var quantity = context.newRecord.getValue({
        fieldId: 'quantity'
        });            
        var rate_ = amount/quantity;
        var newRate = context.newRecord.setValue({
            fieldId : 'rate'
            value : ('rate',rate_)
            });
        }
    }


    return {

        // beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,

    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not syntactically valid. Please replace below code

```
var newRate = context.newRecord.setValue({
  fieldId: 'rate'
  value: ('rate', rate_)
});
```

with

```
var newRate = context.newRecord.setValue({
  fieldId: 'rate',
  value: ('rate', rate_)
});
```

You can try validating your code with JS syntax validator [esprima](http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html). Although alot of IDE's now support validation.

Comment: Now it justs says 'SuiteScript 2.0 entry point scripts must implement one script type function.' but i guess its my code right?

Comment: right, if look in your code,  **beforeSubmit** is commented at the bottom. Uncomment it  and it should work

Comment: This also looks wrong: // Gets the Total Amount
            var amount = context.getValue.getValue({
              fieldId: "amount"
            }); should be // Gets the Total Amount
            var amount = context.newRecord.getValue({
              fieldId: "amount"
            });

Comment: @RustyShackles yes, but that might have already resulted in error.